# Pomodoro Clock break timer not starting

Tags: javascript, function, variables, if-statement

I am finishing up a pomodoro clock and I have everything working just fine, until the timer gets to zero which is the when it is supposed to switch over the break timer but it stays at zero. Any help is greatly appreciated.

http://codepen.io/sammyb123/pen/QyQaPr

```
function start(){
   $("#start").addClass("disabled");
   $("#myreset").addClass("disabled");
   var secs = Number("59");
   var minutes = document.getElementById('mytimer').innerHTML;
   var num = minutes.split("");
   var min = document.getElementById("sessiontime").innerHTML; 
   var min = min-=1;

   if(min > -1){
      startcounter = setInterval(function(){
      secs--;

      if(secs > 9){
         document.getElementById("mytimer").innerHTML = min +":"+ secs;
      } else if(secs >= 0 && secs < 10){
          secs = "0"+secs;
          document.getElementById("mytimer").innerHTML = min +":"+ secs;
            } else if(secs === 0){
                 min--;
                 secs = 59;
                     }       }else if (min === 0 && secs === 00){
    var x = document.getElementById("arrownumid").innerHTML;
    mybreak(x);
  }

  },1000);

}

function mybreak(bt){
   var b = bt;
   var secs = Number("59");


   //document.getElementById("mytimer").innerHTML = mybt;
   min--;
   startBreak = setInterval(function(){
     secs--;
     if(min > -1){
        if(secs > 9){
            document.getElementById("mytimer").innerHTML = b + ":" + secs;
           }else if(secs > 0 && secs < 10){
               secs = "0" + secs;
            document.getElementById("mytimer").innerHTML = b + ":" + secs;
              }else if(secs === 0){
                 document.getElementById("mytimer").innerHTML = "Break Over";
              }

      }
   }, 1000);
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after declaring variables (min, secs and minutes) outside the start function
, just put the last else if inside the setInterval function

so inverse this part

```
},1000);

  }else if (min === 0 && secs === 00){
    var x = document.getElementById("arrownumid").innerHTML;
    mybreak(x);
  }
```

to be as this :

```
  }else if (min === 0 && secs === 00){
    var x = document.getElementById("arrownumid").innerHTML;
    mybreak(x);
 },1000);
 }
```

Comment: I did that as well and no luck. I am sure the problem is in the start function. here is the link to codepen if it helps any, and thank you for the time you put into this. http://codepen.io/sammyb123/pen/QyQaPr

Answer (score 1):

I think your variables

```
var secs = Number("59");    
var minutes = document.getElementById('mytimer').innerHTML;
```

Should be declared outside the function () start .. as that they can be edited in the mybreak function !

Comment: Thank you for that, it does clean things a little. I am still running into a wall in terms of the break timer not starting. I have been on this for much longer than I care to admit lol.

Comment: Ok! .. 

also there is something not correct ... see these lines that you've written

 * var min = document.getElementById("sessiontime").innerHTML; 
* var min = min-=1;

"min" is declared two times ? this will overwrite your var ...

Also, as secs and minutes, the var "min" should be declared outside the start function() also ..

Hope that help

Comment: I did, i removed the var. Thank you for that, I spent too much time on this and my eyes are getting blurry. At this point, I care less about getting it perfect as long as i get it working right.

Comment: I think my last else if in the start() function is not right some how because I test to see if  it gets to it by setting an alert() and the alert never comes up.

Comment: Well seen , the else if should be inside the setInterval .. see my respond below with codes ....

Answer (score 0):

Take a close look at the code below and you'll learn what's wrong with your code.

```
function hms(t, out){
  var h = Math.floor(t/3600), m = Math.floor((t-(h*3600))/60), s = Math.round(t-(h*3600+m*60));
  if(h < 10)h = '0'+h;
  if(m < 10)m = '0'+m;
  if(s < 10)s = '0'+s;
  var r = h+':'+m+':'+s;
  if(out.innerHTML){
    out.innerHTML = r;
  }
  else if(out.value){
    out.value = r;
  }
  else{
    return r;
  }
}
function pomodoro(outputElement, hours, minutes, seconds, doneMsg){
  var h = hours || 0;
  var m = minutes || 0;
  var s = seconds || 0;
  var t = h*3600+m*60+s;
  var d = doneMsg || 'Break Over';
  hms(t, outputElement);
  var timer = setInterval(function(){
    hms(--t, outputElement);
    if(t === 0){
      if(outputElement.innerHTML){
        outputElement.innerHTML = d;
      }
      else{
        outputElement.value = d;
      }
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
// normal use
pomodoro(document.getElementById('mytimer'), 0, 0, 10);
// or
pomodoro(document.getElementById('mytimer'), 1);
// or
pomodoro(document.getElementById('mytimer'), 0, 25);
// or
pomodoro(document.getElementById('mytimer'), 1, 25, 32, 'Your Break is Over Sir');
// abnormal use
pomodoro(document.getElementById('mytimer'), 1, 0, 99);
```

Comment: That is very clean. I am going over that to learn from it but for now I want to learn what I did wrong in my messy code to avoid doing it in the future

Comment: Sloppy indentation. `clearInterval()` never called, when break occurs.

Comment: I do not see what indentation has to do with functionality(I am new so don't expect too much), and clearInterval is called in another function. I only posted what I know is the problem. If you want to look at the overall pic here is the link http://codepen.io/sammyb123/pen/QyQaPr

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you're not using the `stop()` function. Don't make things too complicated.

Comment: I think                 `mysecs = "0" + mysecs;
                document.getElementById("mytimer").innerHTML = b + ":" + mysecs;
            }else if(mysecs === 0){` is the problem, though. You are converting a Number to a String when you do your concatenation, therefore, `mysecs` never equals 0 and you need to use `stop()` when that happens, as well.

Comment: I actually have it in there but it is only activated when the stop button is pressed. It pauses the counter and the start button resumes the count. The reset() function is also there and it only works if the counter is stopped. I know my code has a ways to go to get to where it needs to be but the clock work how I intended it to be.... minus the break counter starting.

Comment: I think you're on your way to figuring it out! Good Luck!